# EHcache with Spring Configruation + JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring, ehcache, jdbctemplate, spring-jdbc

I'm trying to implement cache with spring 3.0

Here is the code that is relevant to the integration:

```
<bean id="cacheManager" class="net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager">
    <constructor-arg index="0" type="java.net.URL" value="classpath:ehcache.xml"/>
</bean>
```

In application-context.xml file

I have a valid ehcache.xml file but it's never read since the application bombs before it gets there, the error I'm receiving is the following:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager] for bean with name 'cacheManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/application-context.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1208)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:568)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1277)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:185)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:805)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:680)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:556)
... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1645)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1491)
at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:258)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:408)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1229)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1200)
```

Does anyone have an idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you should add ehcache-core jar to your classpath... Note to add the right version, though.

EDIT:

note that `ehcache` is used in the `artifactId` and not `ehcache-core`.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
    <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

After running mvn install again, make sure the right jar resides in your local repository and that it contains the right class.

Comment: my current version of ehcache is 1.6.1 though i hav added the  ehcache-1.6.1.jar bt still not working should i post my application-context.xml file. I think i am doing wrong dere.

Comment: I don't think that posting your applicationContext.xml would help. I added the exact maven dependency you should use. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

Please add your ehcache jars to web-inf/lib directory.

If you are using Maven than add this to your pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
    <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I hav added 1.6.1 jar in a builtpath

Comment: @Anurag what is your pom.xml file content ? does it contain the dependency ?

Comment: @AravindA yes sir,                          <dependency>
<groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
<artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
<version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>

Answer (score 0):

If you start your project out of eclipse, check if you have added the ehcache library to the "Deployment Assembly" list.

Open your project's properties dialog -> "Deployment Assembly" and add the lib there.

hth